# Getting RouteHappy RichContent in BFM

Tags: sabre

After much digging in the documents, I found an example of a Bargain Finder Max request that also requests for RichContent(aka. RouteHappy Content).
Following the example, I understand that I have to send the code below, inside the `TPA_Extensions` that also contains `IntelliSellTransaction`:

```
<TPA_Extensions>
    <IntelliSellTransaction>
            <RequestType Name="SOME VALUE" />
    </IntelliSellTransaction>
    <RichContent FlightAmenities="true" />
    <MultiTicket DisplayPolicy="SOME VALUE" />
</TPA_Extensions>
```

With that in mind, when I do send the request, I get an error with the message: `Invalid content was found starting with element 'RichContent'.`

Complete error message:

```
<Errors>
    <Error Type="SERVER" Code="gcc14-isell-tn-00-2021-10-02-5gp8.us-central1-c.c.sab-prod-offers-6532.internal" ShortText="80">
        TOMCAT
    </Error>
    <Error Type="ERR" Code="INVALIDREQ" ShortText="Schema Validation Failed">
        cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'RichContent'. One of '{&quot;http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05&quot;:DiversityControl, &quot;http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05&quot;:MessagingDetails, &quot;http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05&quot;:AlternateAirportCities, &quot;http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05&quot;:AlternateAirportMileage, &quot;http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05&quot;:AwardShopping, &quot;http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05&quot;:Billing, &quot;http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05&quot;:ExchangeSettings, &quot;http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05&quot;:Exchange, &quot;http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05&quot;:PointsRedemption, &quot;http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05&quot;:SplitTaxes, &quot;http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05&quot;:AlternateDatesProcessing, &quot;http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05&quot;:ItineraryCache, &quot;http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05&quot;:MultiTicket, &quot;http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05&quot;:Partitions, &quot;http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05&quot;:ReservationData, &quot;http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05&quot;:AlternatePCC, &quot;http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05&quot;:ResponseControl, &quot;http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05&quot;:BestOffers}' is expected.
    </Error>
</Errors>
```

I am eager to get RouteHappy content working, as it helps provide a richer UX.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to update to `BFM 6.3.0`. That's the version it became available in.